# jenkins - Get Email notification on changed files while building

Tags: .net, git, jenkins, build, config

I use jenkins to build from two GIT repositories.
I also use the Email-ext plugin and i want it to send me when it builds a list of all the files that has been changed since the last build.

(I need this because sometimes configs file are being changed without any sign and I use a config file control tool so i need to update it when a config file changes).

I tried to use $CHANGES but it only gives me the description of the changes form the repository. i need to know which files has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the following

```
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse=true, showPaths=true}
```

If you want just the last build you can change it back to changes. But I like to have all of the changes since the last successful build in case a build fails.
Reverse will show the latest build first and show paths will show the files you edited.